# How can I have logging in public shared library using slf4j?

Tags: java, maven, slf4j-api

I'm writing a public shared library and wanted to have slf4j logging to print some logs without depending specific implementation so that the users of the library can use their own logging framework.

But I'm getting warning as "No slf4j provider specified". How can I have public library with logging without depending on specific implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is role of software that will consume your library to provide slf4j implementation.

You can add slf4j-simple with `<scope>test</scope>` in your pom.xml to use it in your unit tests.